# Tabs at bottom with mapview on top

Tags: android, xml, android-mapview, tabview

Hey people out there..

Im working on making a application with tabview where in one of the tabs is mapview embedded to.
Buut i want the tabview to be at bottom and not on top, when i set the gravity or layout_marginBottom to true it disappers, and is no longer visible on the screen.

Here is the xml file for the tab view activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/emptylayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Any ideas how to get the tabs to bottom and still visible??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
```

This works for me. Place the tabcontent FrameLayout above TabWidget. Please try it out and let me know.

Comment: You are an geniiiiuuus.. :D Thanks alot, really that worked but i have one more question, the map doesnt fill the whole screen, it is like there is an white edge?? anyway to solve that problem??

Comment: **android:background="@android:color/white"** might be the reason for the white edge. Also try by removing **android:padding="5dp"** from the FrameLayout.

Comment: Thanks, solved the problem.. It work with out the padding, there is no edge longer.. Thanks alot it helped me very much :D

Comment: Sorry didnt know how to do it, my first post in stackoverflow.com :D

Comment: Is it possible to ask you for something AmY??

Comment: Yes please. If it is a new question, you may please post it as a new question in stackoverflow and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 1):

I have done it like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs" />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
```